Tiling with one of each 3D shape
Encouraged by the positive solutions to my question,
Tiling with one of each shape,
I'd like to pose the $\mathbb{R}^3$ equivalent:

Q. Is there a tiling of $\mathbb{R}^3$ by (bounded) polyhedra, one each of
polyhedra of $4$ faces, $5$ faces, $\ldots$ ?

The two main versions of Q are (1) allowing nonconvex polyhedra, or
(2) insisting on convex polyhedra.
(Another variant counts vertices rather than faces.)
For (1), Noam Elkies' 2D idea may apply, say using a tiling by congruent cubes,
and partitioning each cube.
For (2), it may be that Martin Tancer's idea can extend
to a spherical design rather than his 2D circular construction.
If both variants are resolved, it would then be natural to generalize to $\mathbb{R}^d$
for $d > 3$.

Martin Tancer's construction works for any integer sequence, not just 3,4,5,6 etc.  So one approach is to just thicken it to a 1x∞x∞ layer and stack such layers to fill 3-space.  A tetrahderon cannot be a prism but we can start with a triangular prism and dissect it to a 4- and 5-hedron.

@NoamD.Elkies: Thanks! But I should stipulate that each tile should be a bounded poyhedron. Will add that now. (Or: I might be misinterpreting $1 \times \infty \times \infty$.)

Partition {5,6,7,8,...} into countably many infinite subsets S_i.  For each one, make a Tancer tiling of the plane by polygons of orders {n-2 : n in S_i}.    Replace each n-gon with a width-1 prism.  That gives a tiling of a 1x∞x∞ layer by polyhedra with face counts in S_i.  Stack them to get a tiling of R^3 by prisms of width 1 which are polyhedra with each face count other than 4 appearing once.  One of them is a triangular prism.  Cut off a corner (=tetrahedron), leaving a pentahedron.  Q.E.F.

@NoamD.Elkies: Thanks for clarifying (I was misinterpreting "1x∞x∞".) Very nice construction!
